# libs3 for listing bucket does not return all bucket contents

Tags: c, amazon-s3

http://docs.ceph.com/docs/hammer/radosgw/s3/cpp/#creating-and-closing-a-connection

I used "LISTING A BUCKET’S CONTENT" section from above link. But I am not able to list all contents of bucket. isTruncated comes to 1 in call back, but nextMarker is null. Any help ?
I will try using aws-sdk but that is too large for my simple needs. And it has gcc 4.9 as requirement.

Comment: It is returning 1000 files, that means I will have to use pagination. But marker is always empty string, so there is no marker ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to save and use the last returned key from the first request as marker for the second request.

The nextMarker is only set in the response if, in your request, you set a delimiter, because when you are using a delimiter, it's not always possible to determine where you should start back up based on the contents of the response.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketGET.html